# How do I get out of a Blender 2.77a Windows 10 infinite loop after setting a .jar default app setting by mistake?

Tags: windows

After some trubosquid downloads, I kept getting a "make default app" for .jar files notice. I clicked okay just to get it to go away. Now when I open Blender 2.77 on my Windows 10 machine the command prompt goes into an "invalid syntax" loop and opens blender window after blender window. It does not do that when I use 2.69 or older versions, but I tried uninstalling and reinstalling 2.77a and the problem persisted. Will changing the default app for .jar files work and how do I do that? What alternative solutions are there?

Comment: UPDATE: I tried the default program thing and I found it didn't work. It is an Import multiray thing and a numpy plugin thing. I deleted them and fount that it didn't work. So I installed 2.76 and installed the plugins I have and found the problem is with a plugin. How do I get to appdata to remove plugins in Windows 10? I can't seem to reach it.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a tutorial on getting into hidden files on Windows 10, like Appdata. From there I just manually deleted all the plugins and reinstalled Blender. It works now.